# How were Monero elliptic curve constants chosen?

Tags: cryptonote, cryptography, elliptic-curve

In the cryptonote paper review, there was a mention about not knowing how the constants were calculated, is there anyway to verify these constants are 'safe' or change them to something 'better'? please enlighten me :DD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it wasn't clear to the reviewers at the time, the constants are standard ed25519 constants from DJB et al. You can read about it [here](http://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf), especially section "Choice of curve" starting on the bottom of page 7.

Comment: I feel like it's important to add that generally the fear with the parameter choices is that they might be 'backdoored' and so normal users will not be able to find `x` for `x.G` or whatever, but someone with some extra info due to the parameters will -- in this case, the parameters were chosen by a researcher (Dan Bernstein) rather than a big company/state organisation/whatever, so the risk is.. different -- it's not that there are really stronger and weaker parameters when it comes to the maths or anything :)